# How to scroll to the last appended piece of text on a TextView?

Tags: xamarin.android, textview, xamarin, android-scrollview, android

So I have a multi-line TextView on my C# Android application. I'm using this as a kind of "status" logger..

So, I might have things like this:

Probing widgets
Proper widget found
Configuring widget

Where each line might take a few seconds to appear because it's something relatively slow.

So, I have a TextView inside of a ScrollView like so:

```
<ScrollView
        p1:minWidth="100px"
        p1:minHeight="100px"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <TextView
            p1:id="@+id/terminalOutput"
            p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
            p1:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
```

This works fine and I can just append to the TextView using the `.Append` method. However, the problem is that eventually there are so many status messages that the text goes down and off the screen. At this point, you have to manually drag in the scroll view to read the latest status messages.

I want it so that whenever a piece of text is appended and it goes off screen for it to scroll the scrollview down so that users can read the latest message without manual scrolling.

How can I do this?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
        Logger = new TextLogger((s) =>
            {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
                          {
                var textview=FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.terminalOutput); 
                textview.Append(s + "\n");
                var scrollview=FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.scrollView1);
                scrollview.ScrollTo(0,scrollview.Bottom);
                textview.ScrollTo(0, textview.Bottom);

            });
        });
```

This kind of works, but it seems like it never quite scrolls to the actual bottom. It scrolls down, but is always like 2 lines away from the bottom, leaving some text still hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ScrollView.FullScroll](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Widget.ScrollView.FullScroll) method instead:

```
scrollview.FullScroll(Android.Views.FocusSearchDirection.Down)
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still scrolls down just about 2 lines short of the actual bottom, causing some text to still be cut off. Could this be something with caching? I've tried disabling caching and such but that didn't seem to help either